# Is there limit on loading Azure AD users programatically using Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We have Azure AD with more than 20k users. I am trying to read all those users with properties such as displayName, city, accountName, department. I am not able to read all users. I am using the skiptoken to get all users, still I am getting each time only few thousands not all users.

Here is my sample code for extracting skiptoken:

```
  public static string ExtractSkipToken(string responseString)
    {
        if (responseString.Contains("skiptoken=X"))
        {
            var startString = "skiptoken=X'";
            var endString = "'";
            var startIndex = responseString.IndexOf(startString, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var subText = responseString.Substring(startIndex + startString.Length);
            var endIndex = subText.IndexOf(endString, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var skipToken = subText.Substring(0, endIndex);
            return skipToken;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Has anyone done that?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD Graph API supports paging as described in [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#PagingSupport). The idea is that the link to the next page of results is provided in the response from the current page. I would recommend not parsing out the skiptoken manually, but rather using the provided link in the JSON response.

If you are following this pattern and the paging is not behaving as expected, please provide more detail on where the paging goes wrong.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I parse the responseString because it has the loaded users information as well. What you mean using the provided link in the JSON response. I followed your refernce and changed my RequestUrl now with $top=999 and I am getting now like 7k or 8k users only.

Comment: I found the problem. It was parsing problem from responseString. I was using ((JObject)result).First.Children() as IJEnumerable<JToken>; to get users from responseString but the statement above not always returning  users which are in the responseString, to collect into my collection, if I use  JObject.Parse(responseString)["value"], i can always collect users which are in responseString. Thank you so much for your help.